# How can I create a Widget that transitions between different SVGs with animation?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a Widget that will contain a list of SVGs (using flutter_svg) and will transition between these SVGs, either on button click or over time. This is a key component of a simple puzzle game I would like to develop.

I have found some third-party packages that allow you to add animations to SVGs, but since I'm doing this for a game, I'm wondering if this is innately supported by either the Casual Games Toolkit or Flame Flutter.

Does anyone here happen to have some experience with this?

Thanks in advance!

Here is what I have tried so far: using an AnimatedSwitcher with a list of SVGs as children. This allowed me to successfully change the displayed SVG on click, but WITHOUT animation.

Answer (score 0):

I actually realized that the reason the AnimatedSwitcher wasn't working properly is that I didn't add a key to the child Widgets, which is how AnimatedSwitcher knows that the new child is a different Widget, and thus should activate the animation.